# check if user has certain service in cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa

Twitter for mac has the *tweet* service, my app want to use *NSPerformService* to tweet some text.

Is there any way to check if the user has certain service, so I can get rid of the alert dialog 'The Tweet actions cound not to be used .......' and use a fallback?

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this on [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DiscoveringSystemServices), but basically you want to use `CFServiceControllerCopyServicesEntries`.